# Return a list of non const pointers by const reference to a list of const pointers

Tags: c++, list, c++11, constants, shared-ptr

I'm facing this problem where one of my objects has a list of `shared_ptr`s to some object. so the type is like this `list<shared_ptr<some_object>>`. But the interface I'm implementing demands that this list be returned from a function with the following signature

`const list<shared_ptr<const some_object>>& getObjList()`.

The compiler won't let me return my list since `list<shared_ptr<const some_object>>&` and `list<shared_ptr<some_object>>&` are not convertable to each other. Is there anyway I can return the required list without having to make a copy whose elements are `shared_ptr<const some_object>`?

Comment: Might be staring the obvious, but depending on what the code needs to do, it might be could be worth trying to reactor your original list nodes to point to const objects. Or simply overriding the present interface so you can pass either sort of list.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible to override the interface. And my list can't be constant because I often take values from and modify them.

Comment: Hmm, id probably just write a conversion function that copies the pointers for now, someone may have a better solution but I can't think of a portable one myself. If it turns out that the copy operation is particularly hot during profiling then you can always fall back on a nasty solution. Maybe using a const list and breaking the const promise whenever it needs to be modified ( profiling before and after ). `Node* node = static_cast<const_cast<decltype(node_ptr.get())>>(node_ptr.get());`

Comment: Ouch! Your API states you have to return a reference to the list of shared pointers, so you can't simply make a copy, as it won't have any lifetime! If you can get rid of that ref, perhaps by pointing out that the lifetime of the returned list should hold the lifetime of the objects in the list, then you can and should make a copy - you would even if it was the same type in order to up the refcounts!

Comment: If the spec is for you to return a "lightweight" object that behaves like a reference to a list of pointers to constants, you could just write a wrapper class that presents a reference to your non-const list and implements begin(), end() that return wrappers to iterators that present the content as a const sharedptr